# DJANGO - using forloop.counter inside a template variable

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I currently have this variable in my template:

```
{{ product_list.0.image_set.all.0.image.url }}
```

It successfully gives the url for the first image in the first product in the product list.

I want something like this:

```
{{ product_list.forloop.counter.image_set.all.0.image.url }}
```

So that I can get the first image of every image in the product_list in a for loop. But the above code does not work. Is this possible?

Comment: First image of every product in the `product_list` you mean? Tried this - `{{ product_list.all.image_set.0.image.url }}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a `forloop.counter`, iterate over `product_list` object by object:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {{ product.image_set.all.0.image.url }}
{% endfor %}
```